# Generating a circular image from planar source

Tags: adobe-photoshop, filter, distort

I have been working in Photoshop CS5 with this particular image:

[image]

What I am trying to do is generate a circle from this, such that the top edge collapses down to a central point and the bottom edge forms the outer radius of the image. How would one go about this, ideally without changing to another piece of software?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's exactly what the Polar Coordinates filter does (*Filter → Distort → Polar Coordinates...*).

Since you want a circle you'll need to distort the image in to a square first (otherwise you'll get an ellipse). The filter will repeat any pixels on the outside edge so you can make your canvas a few pixels taller on the bottom edge so that you get the isolated circle<sup>*</sup>.

[image]

[image]

<sup>*</sup> Otherwise you'll get something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The method with polar coordinates seem already been shown in other texts. But if you use Filter > Distort > Spherize after that, you get a bigger central part.

[image]

Not much imagination is needed to see that you could get maybe fully satisfying result also tiling circles that have transparent gradient fill. That job is most easily done in Illustrator.

Here's an example. One circle with transparent radial gradient fill was drawn. It was rotated & copied 8 times. Rotation angle = 40 degrees. A bigger circle was drawn to the bottom.

[image]

Comment: thanks, now that's a good little extra insight I will take advantage of